# Set language in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a noob in Ruby/Rails and I am creating my first project now.

I am using [Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication system. I have installed it and I am on fight to change the default messages from "en" (default language) to "pt-BR".

I have a file called `devise.pt-BR.yml` inside `/config/locales/` with all translations for this language and I have followed a few tips but when I restart the server, I still get "en" as the default language.

I don't want to have two or more languages, I just need to work with "pt-BR" instead "en".

My environment:

> Fedora 16
>   Ruby 1.9.2p320
>   Rails 3.2.6
>   Devise 2.1.2

`/config/application.rb` content (look at bottom):

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Foo
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('devise', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :"pt-BR"
    I18n.locale = :"pt-BR"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :"pt-BR"
```

to

```
config.i18n.default_locale = "pt-BR"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong, it's working!

I had to drop it inside application.rb:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-BR'
```

And put "devise.pt-BR.yml" inside /config/locales/

I was looking for "Sign in" and label from fields at "Log in" view but I think these strings are not translatable, I will generate these views and manually revise them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your locale file to `pt-BR.yml`, or else change your reference in `application.rb` to `devise.pt-BR.yml`.